# Change the equation font locally

Tags: fonts, equations, amsmath

I want to change the equation font to mathbf in a single equation environment, `equation` or `align`.

How do I do that? I tried

```
\begin{align}
\begin{mathbf}
equation1 \\
equation2
\end{mathbf}
\end{align}
```

and

```
\begin{align}
\mathbf{
equation1 \\
equation2
}
\end{align}
```

with no luck. It seems as if `\\` breaks the `\mathbf` environment..?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For making a complete environment bold, you could use the switch `\boldmath`. `\unboldmath` switches back.

```
\boldmath
\begin{align}
  ax + by + c &= 0 \\
  ax - by &= xy
\end{align}
\unboldmath
```

If `\bf` is available (base classes still define it), `\everymath{\bf}` before the align environment switches to the `\mathbf` font for the complete environment. Of course it could be done without `\bf`, but it would be the quickest way.

Comment: Thanks for your input! It's definitely an option, but it's not quite the same as mathbf. Your solution sets the equation in bold AND italic, which mathbf doesn't.

Comment: @mewoshh: Ok, I focussed on bold - but mathbf is possible, I'lledit.

Comment: @Stefan: `\everymath{\bf}` also effects footnotes

Comment: @Stefan: btw - what if instead of mathbf I want to use any other of the math fonts, for instance mathtt? Can't use mathbold or bf here - there must be a way to use math* in the environment..?

Comment: @Herbert: I know, but footnotes should not be used within a math environment, and after it I would disable this setting. I didn't mean to use `\everymath` simply globally because of such side effects.

Comment: @mewoshh: `\everymath{\tt}` switches to typewriter math font.

Comment: yup, works fine together with \begingroup & \endgroup. Thanks!